# Boxes produced by `mdframed` do not completely outline a region in certain PDF viewers?

Tags: pdf, mdframed, adobe

I am using Adobe Acrobat Professional v. 9, on Windows 8.1. Here's a minimum (not) working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed} % noteboxes, boxes, etc.
\newmdenv[linecolor=black]{notebox}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
    \begin{notebox}
        Here, I am testing out a notebox.
    \end{notebox}

\end{document}
```

This is the output of that example:

[image]

It is worth noting that the zoom level of the PDF affects the output. The above screenshot was taken at 150% zoom. Here it is at 100% zoom:

[image]

Everything works well in Foxit reader, at all zoom levels:

[image]

For some reason though, it is difficult to show the top and left-side lines in the screenshot (even though they appear properly in the PDF viewer), I think because the framed environment has a slight "shadowing" effect that seems to mess things up. Here's the screenshot at a much higher zoom level (1200%), again from Foxit reader:

[image]

Here is a 1200% level screenshot from the same region in Adobe Acrobat. Surprise! It shows up:

[image]

So I am a little confused, and not quite sure what is going on. **How can I set up a robust "boxed text" environment?

Comment: I would say: This is the well-known pdf-viewer issue that lines are not shown correctly. As far as I know this is **not** connected to LaTeX at all

Comment: Try with a different viewer and you'll probably not see the problem. This *is* dependent on your viewer and not a (La)TeX problem.

Comment: Looks like your viewers have problems showing thin lines with low resolutions - that's a known problem and Adobe's products have an extra setting for this.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Could the comments to this question make up a good enough answer, with the additional statement that in order to make `mdframed` boxes display robustly given the failings of pdf viewers, one should bump up the lineweight of the borders?

Comment: @users89: I'll do later on. Bumping up the linewidth is true for any of such packages as `mdframed`.