# weird scaling in PDF when using mdframed

Tags: mdframed

My goal is just to have a simple square box around text and a table.
For this I read to use the `mdframed` package.
I did this and it all worked well when previewing it in Sumatra. I am now finished with my document and opened it in Adobe Acrobat. When previewing it in Adobe the top lien of the `mdframed` is just missing. There it is only when using 70,4% scaling. When going to 100% all lines are there but the bottom and right ones are thicker than the top and left (see pictures attached).
[image: 100% scaling]
[image: 70,4% scaling]
When I want to print it, its the same. I tried the `\mdfdefinestyle` command with `linewidth= 1.5pt`. This helped from disappearing but it nevertheless wasn't the same on all sides.

LaTeX-Code:

```
    \begin{mdframed}%[style=dick]
        \textbf{_Text_}

        _Text_

        % gepunktete Linien
        \setlength\dashlinedash{1.5pt}
        \setlength\dashlinegap{2pt}
        \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}

        \vspace{0.7cm}

        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
            \hdashline
            Ort und Datum & Unterschrift des Prüfungsteilnehmers\\
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{mdframed}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but that your paper is due the day after tomorrow is not a problem that we can solve here. I would think that this is rather a rendering issue. The lines are probably there and have the same width, it is just the PDF viewer that shows them a bit distorted when scaling. You say that if you print the paper it "is the same". The same as what? Do the lines appear correctly or not when printed? Note that your code snippet is not a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Having wrapped your code snippet inside `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{mdframed, tabularx, arydshln} \begin{document}` ... `\end{document}`, I cannot recreate the problem you state. The lines show up in equal thickness.

Comment: @JasperHabicht yes the problem is probably with the pdfviewer. But the pdfviewer is Adobe Acrobat and this is the most standard PDF-Viewer used; especially for a non-IT guy. So my work has to be at least well-formatted in Adobe Acrobat. Is there any way to improve the scaling of the LaTeX PDF?

Comment: There are many issues like that. See [Border in PDF not always visible (depending on zoom), mdframe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/302749/316068), [Box border lines not showing properly on PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11769/316068) or [Boxes produced by `mdframed` do not completely outline a region in certain PDF viewers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237362/316068).

Comment: try `\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Ulrike Fischer I solved the issue.

When using `[framemethod=tikz]` when importing `mdframed`, I can scale the PDF in Adobe to any percent without any issue.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linewidth=1pt, framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mdframed}
        This a wonderful test!
    \end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

This looks bad in the preview of TeXworks but in Adobe Acrobat and Sumatra this is no problem.